# Magento dev environment Can't get sample data deployed

Tags: magento2

I'm completely new on Magento and I'm my goal is to develop a magento plugin. I decided to start with getting a dev environment (which is HARD with this application).

I've found online a tool to build a dev environment here:

https://www.magemodule.com/all-things-magento/magento2-freebies/magento2-docker-vm-script/

I had to make some small changes to get it to work with the latest Magento version (2.4.3).

Everything works well until it tries to pull the sample data (I want to see how a live application works and just go trough the whole admin and user process) it breaks:

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 /app/bin/magento sampledata:deploy
<warning>Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/</warning>
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
<warning>Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/</warning>
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Killed
```

I've tried increasing RAM and it didn't work, I've tried enabling the errors on the `app/bootstrap.php` file but it didn't help.

What should I do?

Is there a better way to build a dev environment and on a repeatable manner?

I just getting frustrated in front of the ammount of folders and "documentation" that is either user or developer related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Killed` most likely comes from the OOM Killer that kills applications that cause the system or (if memory limit is set) container to run out of memory (use too much memory).

Make sure your php container has enough RAM available and increase it if necessary. On a local development environment there isn't really a reason to limit memory consumption of the php container if you have a decent system. I would suggest at least 3-4GB or not limit for your php container. Also, if you use a recent Magento version (like your 2.4.3 version), switching to Composer 2 will improve resource consumption and speed up package installation.

If your PC just doesn't have enough RAM to offer for all the things running, you should get more RAM for it. Just check your memory consumption on your host system when running composer.

**Is there a better way to build a dev environment and on a repeatable manner?**

Create an own environment or use one from GitHub that does not need some custom script. To reduce the points of failure of your local development environment, you should know your setup.

Comment: I've made a RAM upgrade on the Docker desktop app and that worked. I've also customized the `docker-compose.yml` to have more RAM accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I was trying to install 2.4.3-p1 on my docker environment which was created by warden.
I have checked the PHP memory setting of the container is "memory_limit = -1" and also upgrade composer to composer 2.
but I still have this problem.

```
www-data@magento2-php-fpm:/var/www/html$ bin/magento sampledata:deploy
<warning>Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/</warning>
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
<warning>Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/</warning>
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Killed
```

Are there any tips to solve this problem?
Thanks in Advance!