# get magento to use Composer 2

Tags: php, composer, sample-data, memory

I'm actually having [this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344959) but first I want to resolve why it's still looking at Composer 1.

```
me@server:/.../magentoproject$ sudo ./bin/magento sampledata:deploy
[sudo] password for me:
<warning>Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details</warning>
<warning>Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/</warning>
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
<warning>Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/</warning>
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Killed
```

So you can see I'm having the resources issue but first am wondering why it's not invoking Composer 2 as it seems to be installed:

```
me@server:/.../magentoproject$ composer --version
Composer version 2.1.8 2021-09-15 13:55:14
```

Since it's possible Composer 2 could resolve the resource issue, I'm trying to figure that out first.

If it might be helpful, here's my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "version": "2.4.3",
    "require": {
        "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.1",
        "magento/module-bundle-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-cms-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-customer-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-msrp-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-product-links-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-review-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-sales-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-swatches-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-tax-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-widget-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-wishlist-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3",
        "magento/sample-data-media": "100.4.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.4",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.18.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.77",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Why might not it be invoking Composer 2? And as an aside, do you think any enhanced performance would be significant enough so that I won't have to cap PHP heap size (or upgrade my service)?

Comment: what does `sudo composer --version` return? installed composer globally or locally in a `/.../magentoproject` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Add `"magento/composer": "1.7.0 as 1.6.0"` to your `composer.json`'s `require` node and run `composer update`. This is a Composer trick to update Composer to v2 for the project. I've heard from the Magento team that this will be fixed in the next version of Magento, though. :)